# How to display database data hover dynamic description display?

Tags: php, jquery, json, yii

How to display database data hover dynamic description display?  In my project using products pagination  of some product on the product hover i want to show one popup  dynamically what functionally use like `ajax, json` or some  other technology based its possible?

Comment: use jquery tooltip http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: its ok for static data ,right now i want dynamically with db interaction based fetch values what i can use

Comment: @murugan ajax is the best bet with tooltip plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Demo [Ajax Tooltip](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FwKDu)

I am using Jquery UI tooltip,  It is showing your IP address in tooltip from database using ajax request,

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {

    $that = $( this )

            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/', 


            success: function(result){                          
                $that.text(result.ip)                    
            }           
        });
          $( this ).css( position );
          $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "arrow" )
            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: ok i  will implement  your  thought  thank you for responsive

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip({
items: "label , [title]", //as per your html
content: function() {
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'Your url',
      success: function (result) {
               return result;//return result from your url should be a string
}
});
});
```